# Transformer voltage current ratio question

Tags: voltage, current, transformer

Since the voltage increases with a step up transformer, but the current goes down, and since voltage is used to create current, why can't said transformer's output voltage be used to restore the lost current, in case it isn't?

Comment: Current isn't lost. The currents are in two different places, primary and secondary.

Comment: Nothing prevents you to say it, but the theory of electric circuits has been present 150 years and that theory has been good enough with no poetry. Proper theory gives math relations between physical quantities without undefined terms like lost.  A poet may try to earn his living by using as vague terms as possible to give to people a possibility to think "that's true, so true that I have also thought it is just like that".

Comment: true, that's more what i meant, that current in secondary is lower when its voltage is higher, and vice versa. so, thought, since the voltage in secondary is higher in a step-up transformer, shouldn't it be able to regain the lowered current by using the higher voltage with a conductor (before load), since voltage creates current that way?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.

The law of conservation of energy states that energy can neither be created nor destroyed.

In this case, with transformer losses ranging from 1 % to 3 % only, it would not be incorrect to assume that the primary VA (Volts * Amps) and the secondary VA are equal (Vp * Ip = Vs * Is).

Answer (score 1):

Power out = power in (ignoring losses).

Since \$ P = VI \$ we know that

$$ V_{in}I_{in} = V_{out}I_{out} $$

The transformer is transforming power from one voltage-current arrangement to another. It doesn't generate power out of nowhere.

It may help to consider a 55 W, 12 V car headlamp and a 60 W incandescent mains lamp. Both are around the same power but the 12 V lamp will have a thicker filament with much less resistance. The higher voltage lamp will have a higher resistance so it draws less current.

Answer (score 1):

"Voltage up, current down" is correct, but focuses on the wrong thing.

Start with Ohm's law: when you apply a voltage to a resistive load, the current is V/R. Doesn't matter where the voltage comes from; that's always how it works.

When the voltage comes from a transformer, the output voltage of the transformer is V; the load is R, and the current will be V/R. Nothing special here.

It's when you want to know what happens in the **primary** that "voltage up, current down" can help. With a stepup transformer, the voltage on the primary is less than the voltage from the secondary. In order to get the power that's needed by the load, the current in the primary has to be higher than the current in the secondary, because the voltage is lower. That's all there is to it. Nothing is gained or lost from the transformation; power in equals power out.

So "voltage up, current down" simply tells you that if you measure the voltage and current on the primary side, with a stepup transformer the voltage on the secondary side will be higher and the current on the secondary side will be lower.